How to properly quit an event-based thread that needs to clean up resources?
I need to properly quit a thread that only processes signals from another threads. This thread owns a resources that need to be cleaned up. Before the thread will be quit, I call it's abort function, it releases all resources and emits ready_to_abort signal.
In main thread I wait for this signal and after that call quit for this thread.
When the abort slot is triggered by QStateMachine, the program stacks. When the abort slot is triggered by main window, the program finish properly. When I exclude waiting for ready_to_abort signal, the program finish properly, independently of whether this slot is triggered by QStateMachine or main window.
How to perform quit from thread properly?
There is minimum reproducible example:
class Worker(QObject):
    ready_to_abort = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__abort_requested = False

    # This slot is periodically accepts signals from another thread
    # and makes calculations.
    @Slot()
    def process(self):
        if self.__abort_requested:
            return

    # Clean up resources and emit ready_to_abort signal
    @Slot()
    def abort(self):
        self.__abort_requested = True
        print('stopped')
        self.ready_to_abort.emit()

class Process(QObject):

    __abortWorker = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Process, self).__init__(parent)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.workerThread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
    
    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        self.__abortWorker.connect(self.worker.abort)
        self.workerThread.start()

    # There I need to abort a separate thread. That thread contains a resources
    # that requires to be cleaned up. To acheive this goal I emit the signal
    # to that thread and wait while it reported it's ready to abort.
    # If the thread doesn't have such resources and doesn't need to
    # be cleaned up, so I skip a wait stage of this slot, and
    # the program doesn't hang, independently of whether I use state machine or not.
    @Slot()
    def stop(self):
        spy = QSignalSpy(self.worker.ready_to_abort)
        self.__abortWorker.emit()
        if spy.count() == 0:
            print('wait for abort')
            spy.wait(100)
        print('aborted', spy.count())
        del spy
        print('running', self.workerThread.isRunning())
        self.workerThread.quit()
        print('wait')
        self.workerThread.wait()
        print('running', self.workerThread.isRunning())

class MW(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MW, self).__init__()
        self.m = QStateMachine()
        self.s = QState()
        self.m.addState(self.s)
        self.m.setInitialState(self.s)
        self.p = Process()
        self.m.started.connect(self.p.run)
        self.m.stopped.connect(self.p.stop)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.m.start()
        # self.p.run()
        super().showEvent(event)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.m.stop()   # if I comment this line and uncomment next line, the program exits successfully.
        # self.p.stop()
        super().closeEvent(event)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MW()
mw.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())


Why does this have to be in a thread?  If you're just catching and sending signals, why not do that all in the main thread?

@TimRoberts, because this thread processes large data array in signals, but this process doesn't have relation to this problem, hence is excluded from example.

@maestro Your example is invalid. Adding the line print('running', self.workerThread.isRunning()) before the quit and after the wait will show that the code does not hang. This is because the worker does no real work, and you are totally wrong to claim this has no relation to the problem. In your real code, Worker.process probably blocks thread-local event-processing, so abort will never be called. It might be possible to fix this by periodically calling QCoreApplication.processEvents() - but that will depend on exactly how the data processing is done.

@maestro The very fact that the thread processes large data in signals is most certainly related to the problem: as the documentation clearly says, quit() tells the event loop to exit, it doesn't just "interrupt" what the thread is currently doing, and if that thread is being occupied by an unstoppable computation, it will not exit until that computation is completed, because only at that point it will be able to process its event queue and eventually quit. Please provide a proper [mre],

@ekhumoro, you are right, this example is invalid, this program stucks because of app.exec() never return. I've comprehensive investigated my program and revealed that this problem occures when I use QStateMachine and waiting for signal simultaneously. I've updated the example in the question. I've not sure yet whether the QStateMachine or QSignalSpy has relation to the problem. Because QSignalSpy belongs to QtTest framework, I will firstly try to implement waiting via custom event loop. I've updated the question.

@musicamante, of course I know quit() doesn't stop the thread immediately. That's why I've implemented returning from process function when abort is requested.

@maestro With all due respect, we know nothing about your knowledge and experience, so we cannot assume you actually know what quit() does (lots of people don't). And right now your implementation of process is fundamentally pointless in the code you provided, since it returns in any case without doing anything.

@maestro Your updates are no use whatsoever. It's still nothing like a [mre]. As already stated, the worker thread does nothing, so that part of the code is totally pointless. The latest example can be trivially "fixed" by adding the line QApplication.quit() to the end of the stop slot. If you want more productive help, you must provide a complete, fully runnable example script that accurately represents your real application. Anything else is just a waste of everyone's time.
